# Tikz and node with too much spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble, as the first row does not align very well both horizontally and vertically with the rest of my diagram.

[image]

I've tried playing around with left/right but it didn't seem to be of much help.
If I just add the add the arrow (`\node (b) [right=0.1pt of a] {};`), the row's height seems fine:

[image]

but the moment I add the label(`\node (b) [right=0.1pt of a,label=right:Request] {};`), all hell breaks loose.

MVE:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  process_style/.append style={
    rectangle,
    fill=blue!15,
    draw=black,
    thick
  },
  host_style/.append style={
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    dashed
  }
]

% legend
\matrix [draw,below left] at (20.35, -1.5) {
  \node (a) {};
  \node (c) [left=0.1pt of a] {};
  \node (b) [right=0.1pt of a,label=right:Request] {};
  \draw[stealth-, thick] (b) -- (c);
  \\
  \node [process_style, label=right:Process] {}; \\
  \node [host_style, label=right:Machine] {}; \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible solution is playing around the `label` notation.

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  process_style/.append style={
    rectangle,
    fill=blue!15,
    draw=black,
    thick
  },
  host_style/.append style={
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    dashed
  }
]

% legend
\matrix [draw,below left] at (20.35, -1.5) {
  \node (a) {};
  \node (c) [left=0.1pt of a] {};
  \node (b) [right=0.1pt of a] {Request};
  \draw[stealth-, thick] (b) -- (c);
  \\[-2.5pt]
  \node [process_style, label=right:Process] {}; \\
  \node [host_style, label=right:Machine] {}; \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this part of the code differently:

```
  \node (a) {};
  \node (c)[left=0.1pt of a] {};
  \node (b)[right=0.1pt of a,label=right:Request] {};
  \draw[stealth-, thick] (b) -- (c);
```

Indeed, a node that contains nothing has a **minimum width** of `0.3333em`.
  As your node **styles** *(process_style and host_style)* do not specify a width, their width is by default `0.3333em`.
  Instead of starting the arrow at `0.1 pt` from node (a), it is easier to start it at `(a.west)` and end it at `(a.east)`.

That's what gives:

```
  \node[] (a) {};
  \draw[-stealth, thick] (a.west) -- (a.east) node[right=0.3333em of a,inner sep=0pt]{Request};
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  process_style/.append style={
    rectangle,
    fill=blue!15,
    draw=black,
    thick
  },
  host_style/.append style={
    rectangle,
    draw=black,
    dashed
  }
]

% legend
\matrix [draw,below left] at (20.35, -1.5) {
  \node[] (a) {};
  \draw[-stealth, thick] (a.west) -- (a.east) node[right=0.3333em of a,inner sep=0pt]{Request};
  \\
  \node [process_style, label=right:Process] {};\\
  \node [host_style, label=right:Machine] {};\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```